# Xamarin Forms run code when app goes to background (i.e. enteres sleep)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp, background-process

I have an app (iOS, Android, UWP) that retrieves data every minute.  When the app is in the foreground I use a timer to kickoff a call to retrieve the data.
When the app enters sleep state, I want to stop using the timer to retrieve the data and use something that will run in the background and keep running as long as the app is sleeping.  (It is OK if it stops if the app is terminated. 
This app does not required an internet connection as the data source in within the local network the app is connected to.  It appears I have the iOS and Android running using the code shown below.  The challenge I am now facing is getting the UWP version going.

Code in the share code project

Interface Code (I have in a seperate file).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DependencyServiceDemos
{
    public interface IBackgroundService
    {
        Task RunCodeInBackgroundMode(Func<Task> action, string name = "BackgroundService");
    }
}
```

This is the code that will be called to execute in the background.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DependencyServiceDemos
{
    public static class BackgroundCode
    {
        public static bool StopRunning { get; set; } = false;

        public static Timer iobj_timer;

        public static bool GetBackgroundData(int pi_SecondsLoop)
        {
            bool lb_ReturnValue = true;


            // Start a timer that runs after 30 seconds.
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pi_SecondsLoop), () =>
            {
                // Do the actual request and wait for it to finish.
                App.GlobalBackgroundData.MyBackgroundData = "Current Date / Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

                // Don't repeat the timer (we will start a new timer when the request is finished)
                if (StopRunning)
                {
                    lb_ReturnValue = false;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Stopping Background Process: " + App.GlobalBackgroundData.MyBackgroundData);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Background Code Processed: " + App.GlobalBackgroundData.MyBackgroundData);
                }

                return lb_ReturnValue;
            });

            return lb_ReturnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel where I update the data gathered in the background in order to update the UI.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;

namespace DependencyServiceDemos
{
    public class BackgroundData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string is_BackgroundData = "";
        public string MyBackgroundData
        {
            get
            {
                return is_BackgroundData;
            }
            set
            {
                is_BackgroundData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the App.xaml.cs I declare a static instance of my ViewModel as follows:

```
public static BackgroundData GlobalBackgroundData { get; set; }
```

Then I initialize the ViewModel in the app constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
GlobalBackgroundData = new BackgroundData();
```

In the iOS application - I implement the interface as follows:

```
    using DependencyServiceDemos.iOS;
    using DependencyServiceDemos;
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(BackgroundService))]
    namespace DependencyServiceDemos.iOS 
    {
        public class BackgroundService : IBackgroundService
        {
            public async Task RunCodeInBackgroundMode(Func<Task> action, string name = "BackgroundService")
            {
                nint taskId = 0;
                var taskEnded = false;
                taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(name, () =>
                {
                    //when time is up and task has not finished, call this method to finish the task to prevent the app from being terminated
                    Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' got killed");
                    taskEnded = true;
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
                });
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    //here we run the actual task
                    Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' started");
                    await action();
                    taskEnded = true;
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' finished");
                });

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    //Just a method that logs how much time we have remaining. Usually a background task has around 180 seconds to complete. 
                    while (!taskEnded)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' time remaining: {UIApplication.SharedApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining}");
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

I updated the FinishLaunching to register the dependency service as follows:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            DependencyService.Register<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

In the Android project, I implemented the interface as follows:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using DependencyServiceDemos;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IBackgroundService))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.Droid
{
    public class BackgroundService : IBackgroundService
    {
        public async Task RunCodeInBackgroundMode(Func<Task> action, string name = "BackgroundService")
        {
            var powerManager = (PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            var wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial,
                                                    name);
            //acquire a partial wakelock. This prevents the phone from going to sleep as long as it is not released.
            wakeLock.Acquire();
            var taskEnded = false;

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                //here we run the actual code
                Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' started");
                await action();
                Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' finished");
                wakeLock.Release();
                taskEnded = true;
            });

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                //just a method to keep track of how long the task runs
                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();
                while (!taskEnded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Background '{name}' task with wakelock still running ({stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds)");
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
                stopwatch.Stop();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I registered the dependency service in the MainActivity OnCreated event as the last line with the following code:

```
DependencyService.Register<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();
```

So that all seems to work well.  Now I am trying to implement the interface in UWP using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DependencyServiceDemos.UWP.Services
{
    public class BackgroundService : IBackgroundService
    {
        public async Task RunCodeInBackgroundMode(Func<Task> action, string name = "BackgroundService")
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                //here we run the actual code
                Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' started");
                await action();
                Console.WriteLine($"Background task '{name}' finished");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I also initialize the service in the MainPage constructor of the UWP project as follows:

```
DependencyService.Register<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();
```

So from what I can tell the code in the service executes but the following line of code does not appear to execute the BackgroundCode.GetBackgroundData in the static class of my shared code.

Two things:
1.  Is there anything 'wrong' with my implementation for iOS or Android that might get it kicked by the corresponding stores?
2.  Any idea why my UWP code is not working?

```
await action();
```

Comment: Shiny handles background transfers - https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny

Comment: I look at Shiny but it just says backgrounding - which simply means not running on UI thread.  I did not see where it indicated it would do what I wanted which is continually run app code while it is not in the foreground.  The document I found does not even seem to cover what I am talking about.  If I am missing something in the DOCO and you could point me to it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://allancritchie.net/posts/shinyjobs

Comment: Jason - I am still missing something -- I will look through the samples and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @JSON the samples available for Shiny do not compile as downloaded from GitHub.  All kinds of downgraded references - etc.  It is a shame you cant just download the sample you need.  I will try installing the core in my own sample project and getting a job to work.  So far, not a great experience with the product.  Would be nice if the complete documentation were available.

Comment: @Jason - yeah the documentation is not great to say the least.  At this time I feel Shiny is not ready for my app.  I guess I need to look for something else.

Comment: I've never used it, I just know it is supposed to have support for doing background transfers.

Comment: OK I have gotten it all working well now - I hope lol.  I will post a complete solution so everyone has a good working sample in a bit.